# Design of service FAIL handling if Has External integration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service

I have service with 3.party external service integration.

My Service do something in my Database.

if exception occurs on my service then I do not call 3.party service it is ok.

But if 3.party service creates exception. I was already completed operations on my database!

For solve this problem I changed design of service for DB using. All DB operations start with a Transaction and I wait until check 3.party service response. And then I commit that transaction or Rollback for revert my local changes. It seams easy But.

With transactional operation I lock resources until finish the 3.party service response. I think this design dramatically effects service performance. One call waits another call until last transaction finish or rollback.

Do you have best practice knowledge this kind of situate?

My decision Use Database operations without transactional And if 3.party call creates exception Call another Database operation for Revert back to old values to the Database. It is little bit difficult, So find which tables effecting, which changes operating etc..So bored.

But I can see there is only one way. Or I missing some part :/ Thank you.

- Service point
- Create Transaction
- Local Database Operations
- Call 3.party integration service (wait) **Lost time here and transaction lock still exists**
- Commit or Rollback Transaction